# Does @InjectMock replace the bean with a mock in all other beans?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mockito, inversion-of-control

If I annotate

```
@InjectMock
MyClass myclass;
```

in a test, does it mean, that in all cases other beans are initialized with dependency of `MyClass`, they will be initialized with this mocked instance?

In other words, if I have

```
@ApplicationScope
class MyClass {
```

somewhere, it will be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a typo and there should be `@InjectMocks`. For your question:

> does it mean, that in all cases other beans are initialized with dependency of MyClass, they will be initialized with this mocked instance?

As I understand it the answer is no. This

```
@InjectMocks
MyClass myclass;
```

will not create a mock of `MyClass` nor make it anyhow globally accessible (or injected anywhere) but when there is any available it injects other mocks into instance of `MyClass` . For example, if your `MyClass` was like:

```
@Component
public MyClass {
    @Resource
    private SomeResource someResource;
}
```

using `@InjectMocks` would make sense when used like:

```
@Mock
private SomeResource someResource;
@InjectMocks
private MyClass myClass;
```

then any invocation to `someResource` in `myClass` would actually be targeted to the `@Mock` one whice you might then want to stub as needed.

This creation of instance of `MyClass` and injection of mocks to it happens on every `@Test` individually.